# Use C# to connect to SQL Server 2005 through MS Access using ODBC link

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am on a project that requires using C# to connect to SQL Server 2005. I have made two tries:

1. Use `SqlConnection` in C# code. The program prompts that the login failed. However, it is the correct windows login account, which also works when I log into the server directly.

   ```
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
   con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.3.3,1433;database=myDB;User ID=myName;Password=;";
   con.Open();

   con.Close();
   ```
2. Using MS Access Linked table to SQL Server 2005, and use C# to connect to Access database. The connection works when I call `con.Open()`. However, it prompts failed to connect to SQL Server when it runs query at `command.ExecuteReader()`.

   ```
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
   con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\_\Documents\Database6.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
   con.Open();
   string query = "select * from myTable";
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query,con);
   OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   con.Close();
   ```

Thank you very much! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: when you say it works with correct windows account, sound like you are using integrated security and not sql server logins. if that is correct then add to you connection string the following. 'Trusted_Connection=true' and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks you very much Ed, but I still cannot connect to the database.